# Search function — where is it?

Tags: support

I don't seem to be able to find the search function. How do I search for questions with a certain tag or containing a certain string?  I use an iPhone. I'm sure I used to be able to access "search".

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the app or the mobile web site? On the mobile web site, next to the "All Questions" there is a very unobtrusive magnifying glass that took me a while to find. A search box will pop up, but there's no link to remind you of the advanced search syntax.

Here is some of the syntax:

`[tagname]` - limit results to a certain tag
`is:question` or `is:answer` - post type
`user:me` - find posts by you
`title:apples` or `body:"apples oranges"`  - limit words to titles or the body of the post. Only questions have titles, so if you use titles you will only get questions back.

Comment: What search string do I use to search a certain tag (namely, conditional-constructions) for questions with that tag that *have answers by a certain user*, namely me?

Comment: @AlanCarmack you can use `user:me` and `[tag]` in the search box.

Comment: @AlanCarmack `[tag] is:a user:me`.